# Sequelize doesn't return anything if value for $notIn is an empty array but it returns me if array contains an empty value

Tags: arrays, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want Sequelize to return to me all the values which IDs are not in an array.

Sequelize doesn't return anything if value for $notIn is an empty array but it returns me if array contains an empty value.

This returns me nothing:

```
  db.foo.findAll({
    where: {
      id: {
        $notIn: [] 
      }
    }
  });
```

This returns me every value:

```
  db.foo.findAll({
    where: {
      id: {
        $notIn: [''] 
      }
    }
  });
```

How come it doesn't return all values if the array is empty? If it is empty, then it means all values which values are not in that array should be returned. Since the ID doesn't contain any value, sequelize should return to me all the values, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in Sequelize version 4. That version has not been fully disclosed yet, though. At least there is no documentation yet.

See the GitHub issue at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4859.

The changelog can be found at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md. It says

> [FIXED] $notIn: [] is now converted to NOT IN (NULL) #4859

Maybe you can implement those version 4 changes in your current code yourself.

Comment: Yes, and I did already. It was just kinda weird and I wanted to know why. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

For those using < 4 version, here is a work around I used,

```
let idsToSkip = [...]; //generate array of ids, this may result in empty array
idsToSkip.push('-1'); // push a value that can not be the id in table. this will generate `not in ('-1')` query serving the purpose.
db.foo.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      $notIn: idsToSkip
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps !!